# Split separates strings and ignore/remove other delimited string

Tags: c#

I'm reading a comma-delimited list of strings from a config file. I need to check the following steps

```
1) check to see if the string has `[`, if it is then remove or ignore...
2) split `,` `-` //which i am doing below...
```

Here is what I able to do so far;

```
string mediaString = "Cnn-[news],msnbc";

string[] split = mediaString.Split(new Char[] { ',', '-' }); //gets me the bracket
```

what I want is to ignore/remove the string which is in the brackets so the end result should be like this:

```
mediaString = 
                Cnn
                msnbc
```

Comment: Can't you use a regular expression to remove the [news]? `Regex.Replace(mediaString, @"[.*]", "");`

Comment: What are the more general rules for this?  Is it remove any substrings with square brackets? Or any entry?  For example, if the inputs were "Cnn-News [Channel] 9,msnbc".  Is the expected output then going to be `Cnn`, `News 9`, `msnbc`? Or in that case, are the brackets to be ignored and the output left as `Cnn`, `News [Channel] 9`, `msnbc`?

Comment: the general rule based on my string array the output should be `cnn,msnbc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
mediaString.Split(new Char[] { ',', '-' }).Where(val => !val.Contains('[')
```

You can make the test (`val.Contains(...)`) as sophisticated as you like (e.g. starts and ends with, regular expression, specific values, call an object provided via a DI framework if you want to get all enterprisey).

Comment: To make it a little more accurate:
`.Where(val => !val.StartsWith("[") && !val.EndsWith("]"));`

Comment: Technically, @Abu asked just if it contained '[' :), but, to your point, one could add pretty much anything to the condition check, including regular expressions.

Comment: what is the return? string[] ?

Comment: @Abu IEnumerable<string>, or if you need string[] add .ToArray().

Comment: If you can't do it with Linq, you've got to ask if it's really worth doing :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex replace to clean your string

```
        string str = @"Cnn-[news],msnbc";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[.*\]");
        string cleanStr = regex.Replace(str, "");
        string[] split = cleanStr.Split(new Char[] { ',', '-' });
```

Comment: the out put i am getting is `cnn -` which i am not looking for, pls see my question for the output i looking

Comment: I have run the code and the output is `Cnn` , `` , `msnbc`, the reason for that is that after removing the string look like `Cnn-,msnbc` so I think the result is valid

Answer (score 0):

Without using LINQ or regex:
Split your string as you are doing now.
Create a data structure of string type for example: List.
Run over the results array and for each entry check it contains the specified character, if it doesn't add it to the List. 
In the end you should have a List with the required result.

This The regex solution is far more elegant but if you cannot use reg ex this one should do it

Comment: i know i could use those checks but i thought there should be a better way of doing then check all those `if conditions`

Comment: Then regex is your best choice